# Missing prompt "implements interface X" when implements a generic type

Tags: typescript

So, i have two classes: A and B.
What i want to do is to make class A implements all public properties of class B. So i wrote a generic type:

```
type PropertiesOf<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }
```

And when i use it like that:

```
class A implements PropertiesOf<B> { }
```

Its an error on A:

> "Type A is missing the following properties from type
>   'PropertiesOf': ..."

So its seems to work.

But the only prompt on A class definition is

> "Move to new file"

If i wrote a simple type, fe:

```
type X { a: () => {}; }
```

the prompt is

> "implement interface X"

So, it is something wrong with `PropertiesOf` type, or is that something else?

Comment: _class A implements all public properties of class B_ Class A can also extend class B and by that, class A will have all the properties of class B too?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. VSCode throws a bunch of errors to the console when I try to get fixes at the location of `PropertiesOf<B>`